# Using Menelaus' Theorem to show points are collinear

Tags: geometry

I have the following statement that I need to prove. I know I need to use Menelaus' Theorem but I honestly don't even know what the picture looks like. Help would really be appreicated.

> "D,E,F are the points of contact of the in-circle of a triangle with the sides BC, CA, AB respectively. If EF, FD, DE meet these sides respectively at P,Q,R, show that P,Q,R are collinear.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is the Desargus' Theorem. You have that $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEF$ are perspective centrally, so they must be merspective axially. This means that $P-Q-R$ are collinear.

To prove that $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle DEF$ are perspective centrally you need to show that $AD, BE$ and $CF$ concur at one point. This well-known and the point where the concur is known as the Gergonne Point. Anyway it can be easily proven by Ceva's Theorem.

---

If you insist on using the Menelaus' Theorem you have a bit longer proof. Applying the theorem on the lines $D-E-R$, $D-F-Q$, $E-F-P$ and mutiplying the three equations you will get:

$$\frac{CQ}{AQ} \times \frac{AR}{BR} \times \frac{BP}{CP} = \left(\frac{FB}{FA} \times \frac{AE}{EC} \times \frac{CD}{BD} \right)^2 = 1$$

As we have $\frac{FB}{FA} \times \frac{AE}{EC} \times \frac{CD}{BD} = 1$ from the Ceva's Theorem on the Gergonne Point and $\triangle ABC$. So by Menelaus' Theorem $P-Q-R$ are collinear.